# Computing a small part of an array that is too big to store

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider the code below.  It creates a 2d array having `i` columns and `2**i` rows.  In this case, the shape is (10,1024).  The rows show consecutive binary numbers from `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` to `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` listed in ascending order (left to right).
I then use slicing to examine small ranges of **consecutive array rows** (eg: `out[990:995]`).  Everything works as expected.

```
import numpy as np

i = 10
r = np.arange(2**i)   

out = (((r[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(i)))) > 0).astype(int)
out = out[:,::-1]    # for ascending left to right
```

Here's the problem:  The actual values of `i` can be larger (say, `i=30`, producing over a billion rows), so I'd like to not keep creating a huge array only to examine tiny portions of it.  I get memory error "Unable to allocate 120 GiB..."

**QUESTION:** Let's say `i=30`, and I need to find `out[1006200:1006211]`.  Is there a way to efficiently do this **WITHOUT computing the entire array?**

For what its worth, the desired output would be an array of shape (11, 30):

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]
 ...

 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate on dynamic range with `low/high` bounds:

```
def calc_on_range(low, high, i=10):
    r = np.arange(low, high)
    out = (((r[:, None] & (1 << np.arange(i)))) > 0).astype(int)
    return out[:, ::-1]

print(calc_on_range(low=1006200, high=1006211, i=30))
```

---

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]]
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I learned something really useful.